# Need help for fixing a HTML code

Tags: html

I'm learning HTML and I've made a program I need help for. I have written all the code but I want the pictures BOB 1/2/3 to be next to each other. Futhermore I don't know why I can't see the "Home". Also want that the the information at the buttom of the page should be next to each other

Thanks in advance :)

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>My first website</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=divice-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<style>
body{
background: #00FF33;
font-family: Verdana, Tahama, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 18px;
overflow: auto;
}
h1, h2, h3 {
text-align: center;
padding-left: 5%;
color: #000066;
}
p {
padding: 2%
color: #000066;
}
img {
text-align: center;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
width: auto;
}
#wrapper {
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 1020px;
width: 98%
background: #000000;
border: 1px solid #878E63;
border-radius: 2px;
box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0px rgba(12, 3 , 25, 0.8);
}
#callout {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
background: #000000;
overflow: hidden;
}
#callout p{
text-align: right;
font-size: 13px;
padding: 0.1% 5% 0 0;
color: #FFFF00;
}
#callout p a{
color: #CC0000;
text-decoration: none;
}
header {
width: 96%;
min-height: 125px;
padding: 5px;
text-align: center;
}

nav ul {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding-left: 50px;
}
nav ul li {
float: left;
border: 1px solid #878E63;
width: 15%;
}
nav ul li a {
background: #F1F0D1;
display: black;
padding: 5% 12%
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 18px;
color: #878E63;
text-decoration:none;
text-align: center;
}
nav ul li:hover, nav ul li.active a {
background-color: #878E63;
color: #878E63;
}
.banner img {
width: 100%;
border-top: 1px solid: #878E63;
border-bottom: 1px solid: #878E63;
}
.clearfix {
clear: both;
}
.BobContainer{
width: 29%;
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
margin: 0 1.666%;
}

.left-col {
width: 55%;
margin: -2% 1% 1%;
float: left;
}

.sidebar {
width: 40%;
float: right;
margin: 1%;
text-align: center;
}
.hallo{
float: left;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
padding: 1%;
}
.section{
width: 29%;
margin: 2% 2%;
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
}
footer{
background: #878E63;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}
footer p, footer h3{
color: #F1F0D1;
}
footer p a{
color: #F1F0D1;
text-decoration: none;
}
ul{
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
li {
display: inline;
}
ul li img{
height: 50%;
}

.footerLogos{
width: 45%;
margin: 0 2.45%;
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
}

/*---------MEDIA---------*/
@media screen and (max-width: 478px){
body{
 font-size: 13px;
 }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 740px){
nav{
width: 100%;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
nav ul{
list-style: none;
margin: 0 auto;
padding-left: 0;
}
nav ul li{
text-align: center;
margin-left: 0 auto;
width: 100%;
border-top: 1px solid #878E63;
border-left: 0px solid #878E63;
border-bottom: 1px solid #878E63;
border-right: 0px solid #878E63;
}
nav ul li a{
padding: 8px 0;
font-size: 16px;
}
.left-col {
width: 100%;
}
.sidebar{
width: 100%;
}
.section{
float: left;
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
}
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="callout">
<p>Call us at <b>123456</b></p>
</div>
<header>
<a href="#"><img src="http://www.logodesignbuzz.com/creativelogos/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/alnabulsi-creative-logos.jpg"</a>
</header>

<nav>
<ul>
<li class='active'><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Prices</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Who are we?</a></li>
</ul>

</nav>
<div class="banner">
<img src="http://www.logodesignbuzz.com/creativelogos/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/alnabulsi-creative-logos.jpg"</a>
</div>

<section class="left-col">
<p style ="text-indent: 50px;">Restaurant websites are a great place to find inspiring designs and also to check out some nice ways of displaying photographs within a design. Since the main content of a restaurant is their food – or at least it should be – there is no better thing to do than show beautiful images of the food</p>
<p style ="text-indent: 50px;">HELLOZZ</p>
</section>
<aside class="sidebar">
<img src="http://www.logodesignbuzz.com/creativelogos/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/alnabulsi-creative-logos.jpg"</a>
 <div class="hallo">
</div>
 </aside>

 <div class="BobContainer">
 <h3>BOB1</h3>
 <img src="http://www.logodesignbuzz.com/creativelogos/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/alnabulsi-creative-logos.jpg"</a>
 <p>Du</p>
 </div>
<div class="BobContainer">
 <h3>BOB2</h3>
 <img src="http://www.logodesignbuzz.com/creativelogos/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/alnabulsi-creative-logos.jpg"</a>
 <p>Er</p>
 </div>
 <div class="BobContainer">
 <h3>BOB3</h3>
 <img src="http://www.logodesignbuzz.com/creativelogos/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/alnabulsi-creative-logos.jpg"</a>
 <p>Dum</p>
 </div>
 
 <footer>
 <div class="footerLogos"
 <p>Call us at:</p>
  <p><b>123456</b><br>
  Or write to<br>
  www@hotmail.com<br>
  2670 Greve</p>
  </div>
  <div class="footerLogos"
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#"><img src="http://www.adweek.com/socialtimes/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2013/04/2-150x150.png"</a></li>
<li><a href="#"><img src="http://virtualmarketingpro.com/blog/empreendeglobal/wp-content/uploads/sites/897/2015/01/logo-youtube-335x320.png"</a></li>
 </ul>
   <div class="footerLogos"
 <img src="http://www.logodesignbuzz.com/creativelogos/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/alnabulsi-creative-logos.jpg"</a>
  </div>
 </footer>
 </div>
<p style="text-align: center; padding:0px;">&#169;Copyright - hala hala, 2015</p>
 
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please trim this down and remove all the excess code.

Comment: I thought you needed it all ?

Comment: no. We need enough to reproduce, diagnose, and fix the problem. We don't need or want irrelevant code.

Comment: To be honest I don't know what you would consider as irrelevant code. It's my first website, so I'm an amateur :)

Comment: Please read about how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also, you seem to be asking at least 3 questions. Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: You need to know that writing HTML markup is not "programming". HTML is a markup language for structuring a document and not a programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CSS Code Try Adding To **Section** Styles : `display: inline-block;`

Also Delete : `float : left;`

Comment: Only The One Which Is In The Section Styles

Comment: Bob 2/3 are next to each other now but bob 1 is over them

Comment: Change this things in your code. First : Add a new classs in the css archive called 'BobContainer', Second : In your HTML Code go where Bobs are and change 'class = "section" ' for 'class = "BobContainer" ', Third : Back to Css archive and copy all Section Styles and paste them in the class 'BobContainer'

Comment: And Finally : In the Css archive again go to 'BobContainer' and change the property width to --> 30%

Comment: So like this:  `.BobContainer{
width: 29%;
margin: 2% 2%;
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
float: left;
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
}`

Comment: Delete Float Property And Notice You Have 2 Margin Properties Delete One Of Them And Change The Other For 'margin : 0  1.666%;'

Comment: like this?: `.BobContainer{
width: 30%;
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
float: left;
margin: 0 1.666%;
}`

Comment: Change width to 29%, I made the operation with your previous value

Comment: Im can make another answer to post the right code there if you want

Comment: You have to change the class of all Bobs to 'BobContainer' Bob 2 and 3 still have section class, change widht property in 'BobContainer' class to 29% and delete 'float : left' in the same class

Comment: have changed it but still get the same

Comment: what about the youtube/facebook logo?

Comment: Ok sorry  the other comment was wrong dont pay attention to it

Comment: I have seen you have 3 or 4 DIV tags not closed like this : '<div class = section' you need to close them whit '>'         Can I edit your code ?

Comment: Im sorry but StackOverFlow doesnt let me to edit your code, here you have a fiddle with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/h1hk9Ldm/3/, logos seems to be not inline, but its because of the image you took, if you see margins both logos are inline

Comment: try opening this file with your browser and look what I mean: filedropper.com/website_1

Comment: That's not a public domain, if I open It doesn't show me your webpage, however the code runs in my computer, be sure you have edited yours in filedropper.com

Comment: http://www.filedropper.com/website69    Thats the archive with the corrections i just have edited some Css styles and added one container where i have pushed BOBs